# Getting TypeError while useing MetricsGraphics.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to plot some Time-Series data use [MetricsGraphics.js](http://metricsgraphicsjs.org/), but can't seem to get it to work and I couldn't find an answer anywhere online.  Metrics is built on top of D3.js

The error is:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at process_line (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/metrics-graphics/dist/metricsgraphics.js:4211:50)
    at Object.charts.line.init (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/metrics-graphics/dist/metricsgraphics.js:2333:13)
    at Object.charts.line (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/metrics-graphics/dist/metricsgraphics.js:2973:14)
    at Object.MG.data_graphic (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/metrics-graphics/dist/metricsgraphics.js:216:20)
    at init (http://localhost:9000/pages/home/home-controller.js:46:12)
    at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:9000/pages/home/home-controller.js:59:5)
    at invoke (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4182:17)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4190:27)
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8453:28
    at link (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js:981:26) <div class="container ng-scope" ng-view="">
```

And here is the code that makes the chart object:

```
MG.data_graphic({
          title: "Projector Usage",
          description: "Projector Usage in Folsom.",
          data: chartData,
          width: 800,
          height: 450,
          target: "#chart",
          x_accessor: "date",
          y_accessor: "value"
        });
```

This piece of code is generating the JSON Object Array:

```
for(var x=0; x < data.length; x++){
            chartData.push({
                            date  : new Date(data[x]['timestamp']),
                            value : data[x]['result']['projectorsOn']
                          })
          }
```

Answer (score 2):

So..... It was a stupid mistake.  The MG.data_graphics was trying to access chartData before I had called the asynchronous data call that populated the object.

To fix the issue, I just added that function into the $http.post().success() callback.